# Is there a way to do assign or append a variable in one-line if-statement in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Because of variable is get from cache so it could be NoneType or list, 
just wondering about append or assign in one-line if-statement instead of

```
if result:
    result.append(data)
else:
    result = [data]
```

I've already try about:

```
result.append(data) if result else [data]
```

but the code return only will have one element in it.

Comment: What is this cache, and why are the values you retrieve from it sometimes None and sometimes lists? If you're using a dict, consider [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) or [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault).

Comment: You've also got the problem that `result = [data]` won't write back to the cache, while `result.append(data)` mutates an existing list, which likely will affect the cache, depending on what the cache actually is.

Comment: The ternary `if`/`else` operator is desined to be an expression (unlike the `if` statement). Having side effects in an expression is often considered a bad practice since it makes the code less clear and readable. I advise to stay with your first example. Also there's a subtle difference in your code sample.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to do this is

```
# initialize
result = []

for ...
    result.append(data)
```

However, note that many applications of `for` with `append` can be replaced by a list comprehension.  If you're not familiar with that Python structure, I strongly recommend that you work through a tutorial on the topic.